# A trace size quota was exceeded. The trace was truncated

Tags: c#, wcf

I keep getting a "A trace size quota was exceeded. The trace was truncated." error, even when I put my maxBufferPoolSize, maxReceivedMessageSize, maxArrayLength, maxBytesPerRead values to 20000000

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IRemoteRoutePlanner" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="20000000"
                        maxArrayLength="20000000" maxBytesPerRead="20000000" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                            algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFBetterplace/Service1/"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IRemoteRoutePlanner"
                contract="RemoteBetterplaceReference.IRemoteRoutePlanner"
                name="WSHttpBinding_IRemoteRoutePlanner">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

You can se the project code here: https://github.com/Vandborg/dm76-vandborg

Reason for a link to all the code is a I really really don't know where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
   <httpRuntime executionTimeout="90" maxRequestLength="80000000"/>
</system.web>
```

Check this in your IIS or Visual Studio host application.

Comment: I'm not sure where to add this. But I've added in app.config file in the bottom just before </configuration>. But I still get the same error.

Comment: Both the client and server should be filled with values:

<readerQuotas maxdepth = "32" maxStringContentLength = "20000000" maxArrayLength = "20000000" maxBytesPerRead = "20000000" maxNameTableCharCount = "16384" />

Whether they are properly added to the configuration files?